# Get the week index of each date?

Tags: python

How would I get the week index of which the dates fall into for each year.  I have a list of dates from random years from 2013 on and I would like to index each week and apply that to an array to do some analytics on.

Basically I want to group all of my data by week.

```
 3-Mar-15
 1-Apr-14
 27-Aug-14
 18-Jan-13
```

Comment: Look into [the datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html). It's pretty nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import dateutil.parser
data = ['3-Mar-15', '1-Apr-14', '27-Aug-14', '18-Jan-13']

[dateutil.parser.parse(x).isocalendar()[1] for x in data]

Out[117]: [10, 14, 35, 3]
```